# Creating a function to check two lists against each other

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a function which will scroll through a every row in a sheet and compare a certain  column's  value (W) to a column (which is always T) in all the other sheets in the workbook. If the value matches then the row has a corresponding row in the other sheets.

To add some context, the objective is to flag up any rows in the main sheet which don't have a corresponding row in the other sheets. So far I have this:

```
For x = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
  If Sheets(x).Name <> "VAT Transaction Report" Then
    Dim Search(x) As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set Search(x) = Sheets(x).Range(Cells(1, 16), Cells(LastRow, 17))

    With Sheets("VAT Transaction Report")
      LastRow = .UsedRange.Row - 1 + .UsedRange.Rows.Count
      For y = 2 To LastRow
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(y, 1).Value = False) And IsEmpty(.Cells(y,24).Value = True) Then 
          .Cells(y, 24).Value = Application.VLookup(.Cells(y, 24), Search(x), 2, False)
        End If                    
      Next y
    End With
  End If
Next x
```

This code doesn't work as my range Search(x) has to be constant, but I want a range for each sheet in my workbook, is there anyway to do this?

Edit:
Following suggestions my code is now

```
Sub search()

  Dim search() As Range, x As Integer, v As Integer
  v = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
  For x = 1 To v
    If Sheets(x).Name <> "VAT Transaction Report" Then
      ReDim search(x)
      Dim LastRow As Long
    * Set search(x) = Sheets(x).Range(Cells(1, 16), Cells(LastRow, 17)) *
      With Sheets("VAT Transaction Report")
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Row - 1 + .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For y = 2 To LastRow
          If IsEmpty(.Cells(y, 1) = False) And IsEmpty(.Cells(y, 24) = True) Then
            .Cells(y, 24).Value = Application.VLookup(.Cells(y, 24), search(x), 2, False)
          End If        
        Next y
      End With
    End If
  Next x

  With Sheets("VAT Transaction Report")
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Row - 1 + .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For y = 2 To LastRow
      If IsEmpty(.Cells(y, 1) = False) And IsEmpty(.Cells(y, 24) = True) Then
        .Cells(y, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      End If
    Next y                 
  End With
End Sub
```

However this is throwing up application or object defined errors on the * marked row

Comment: `Set Search(x) = Sheets(x).Range(Sheets(x).Cells(1, 16), Sheets(x).Cells(LastRow, 17))`

Comment: The problem arises when I "Dim" Search(x), stating that a constant expression is required

Comment: use`dim search():redim search(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)`

Comment: That's because it's looking for constant x. You're basically declaring an Array of ranges (with the `Search(x)` part)

Comment: try the redim o/s the loop, the way I showed.